# Justifying Steps For Finding Limit Of Sequence Using Uniform Convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose we want to solve $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(\left(n+1\right)^{\frac1 4}-n^{\frac1 4}\right)$$ By using series expansion.
We have

$$a_n=n^{\frac1 4} \left(\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{\frac1 4}-1\right)$$
Now let $$f:\mathbb N\setminus {1}\rightarrow (0,0.6) ~~~;n\mapsto \frac 1 n$$ and $$g(x)=(1+x)^{\frac1 4}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom {\frac 1 4}{k}  ~x^k ~~;~ x\in(0,0.6)$$
Since this  power series converges uniformly in $(0,0.6)$. we have composition $g\circ f$ uniformly converges on $\mathbb N\setminus {1}.$
So by uniform convergence we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom {\frac 1 4}{k}  \cdot\left(\frac {1} {n^k}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}  \left(\binom {\frac 1 4}{k}  \cdot\left(\frac {1} {n^k}\right)\right)=1.
$$
I want to use this method for

$$n^{\frac1 4} \left(\left(1+\frac 14 \cdot \frac 1n+\cdots\right)-1\right)$$.
And In some book they factor out $\frac 1 n$ from series. And  then applying limit term by term.

> (1):My question Is Author really check that after factor out $\frac 1 n$ new series of function is uniformly convergent.?
>
> If Answer of the question $(1)$ is yes. Then how can we justify uniform convergence quickly in such a case.
>
> Or there is something different general theorem they are using there for applying limit term by term. That we can use in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

The uniform convergence of $g\circ f$ is not sufficient, since you multiply $g\circ f(n) $by $n^{1/4}$.

When $x \in ]0,1]$, the series giving $g(x) = (1+x)^{1/4}$ is alternated and the absolute value of the general term decreases (to see that, look at the ratio of two consecutive terms). Hence the absolute value of the remainder $$g(x)-1 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{1/4}{k}x^k$$
is bounded above by the absolute value of $\binom{1/4}{k}x^k$, namely $x/4$. Thus, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $n^{1/4}|g(1/n)-1| \le n^{-3/4}/4$. This gives the convergence to $0$.

Comment: I didn't get how it can  be used. Does it imply new series ( after multiply by $n^{\frac 1 4}$ will be uniform?

Comment: And now, do you see?

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I  want to know that why in my book author apply term by term limit .  Because this term by term limit used in lots of example .so I want to know why it works.

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem applies, provided you bound above $|n^{1/4}{1/4 choose k}(1/n)^k|$ by some sequence which is independent of $n$ and is the general term of a convergent series.

Comment: Can you provide solution using dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Multiplication and division with $((n+1)^{1/4} + n^{1/4})((n+1)^{1/2} - n^{1/2})$ gives another approach?